# SPA client doesn't send a cookie when Spring Authorization Server logout url is requested

Tags: session-cookies, logout, spring-authorization-server

I make Spring Authorization Server for all API's in  my organization. It is deployed on domain https://oauth.organization.com. The problem is that client SPA  deployed on https://app1.organization.com requests SAS logout uri.Javascript client doesn't send a cookie because of CORS and SAS doesn't invalidate a server session.

I have following brainstormings:

1. To oblige all SPA clients to permit cookie between cross site domains- this will increase the security risk;
2. To implement custom logout logic - token based not session based.

I'll be looking forward for ideas

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Have you tried enabling CORS? Please share what you've tried so far, and we can try and guide you based on that.

Comment: I try to follow all requirements of Spring Authorization Server.I have enabled the CQRS, but when I'm sending logout request the browser is not sending a cookie and SAS is not  logging out. When I activate Same-Site:None the browser sends a cookie and everything works fine , but I'm not sure that is correct. My question is : What is the best way to solve this problem and to log out client from SAS. Thanks in advance.